# multiple condition c++

Tags: c++, opencv, if-statement, conditional-statements

What is the best way to code this condition in C++?

I tried to code it, but it alredy looks too complicated and has errors when compiling

```
                     if(alpha <= hsv_image[2].at<float>(i,j)/hsv_bkg[2].at<float>(i,j))
                                {
                         D = min(...);
                                    if( abs(hsv_image[1].at<uchar>(i,j)-hsv_bkg[1].at<uchar>(i,j))<=T_value && D<=T_value){
                                        ...

                                    }
                                }
                }
```

Comment: `...` is not valid syntax. Please show a [mre] with code that reproduces your problem and the exact error message

Comment: What is the `∧` symbol in the picture representing? Is it really xor or is it a [logical conjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction)?

Comment: this is AND operator

Comment: Also A is && of two inequalities

Comment: The general way (not only in programming) to deal with complexity is *divide et impera,* or ["divide and conquer".](https://www.open.edu/openlearn/science-maths-technology/approaches-software-development/content-section-1.5) In programming it's one of the central tenets. In this particular case: Assign the various expressions to aptly named variables and perform the top-most computations and the comparisons with those. Add more intermediate layers when necessary. Pay attention to variable names: They are perhaps the single most important contribution to understanding a program.

Comment: A while ago I gave an example for naming and decomposition into smaller, more manageable pieces [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33241669/3150802)

Comment: Since this is a OpenCV code, I added OpenCV tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see, you are using OpenCV. I'm right now learning it myself and I'm not expert, but I see that you are trying to do operations pixel by pixel. This causes a HUGE performace issue in OpenCV. You need to operate on whole picture at once.

For example, your equation can be written in OpenCV as something like this(maybe it has bugs, it came quickly off top of my head and I'm learning myself):

```
Mat mask1, mask2, sub, res;
divide(IV, BV, mask1);
inRange(mask1, Scalar(alpha), Scalar(beta), mask2);
abs(IS - BS, sub);
auto D = min(...);
bitwise_and(sub, D, res, mask2);
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I can read out of it, you could calculate the three inner conditions first:

```
auto val1 = IVt(x,y) / BVt(x,y);
bool cond1 = alpha <= val1 && val1 <= beta;

auto val2 = ISt(x,y) - BSt(x,y);
bool cond2 = val2 <= Ts;

bool cond3 = Dh <= Th;
```

And then the result should be:

```
bool result = cond1 && cond2 && cond3;
```

Comment: He is using openCV but incorrectly. He need to optize his code bu doing it over whole image rather than pixel by pixel.

Comment: Also, aren’t those xor symbols?

Comment: @mreff555 No, they are logical conjunction symbols - `AND` symbols that is.